# In my function call I keep getting an error for "primary-expression before 'char'"

Tags: c++, function, call

I do not understand what is missing in front of char. The line is:
float temp = tinputs(char scale);

I mean I've tried a ton and didn't get passed the error statement. it should be a simple fix though.

Comment: Please edit a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue into your question.

Comment: If you intend to call the `tinputs` function and pass it the `scale` variable then do not declare the function's argument type: instead of `float temp = tinputs(char scale;)` write just `float temp = tinputs(scale);`. But if you are only declaring the functuon then do not try to assign its return value: then write `float tinputs(char scale);`.

Comment: Pro tip: don't paraphrase error messages; they usually contain lots of useful information, and if you're lost in the message then you're not in a position to decide what's important and what's not. At the very least, the error message quoted in the title leaves out the word "expected" at the beginning. In this case, that doesn't affect the answer, but don't build bad habits.

Answer (score 0):

From the limited information you've provided I assume you're trying to call function `tinputs` with argument scale type `char`.
However you're using a declaration syntax in a call function.

Your code should be like this:

```
float temp = tinputs(scale);
```